# Load Javascript when element is in view

Tags: javascript, html, lazy-loading

So I've had some assistance to create a javascript element which spins from "0" upto "190" however, this is triggered when the element is in view - so I thought - it turns out the number is ONLY increased when you scroll.... For example:

Script:

```
    var totalShipped = 190;
    var shippedDisplay = 0;
    var shippedStep = totalShipped / (2 * 1000 / 100); // Animation duration 2 sec
    $(allInView);
$(window).scroll(allInView);


function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
    function allInView() {
      if (shippedDisplay > totalShipped)
        shippedDisplay = totalShipped;
      document.getElementById("shipped").innerHTML = Math.round(shippedDisplay);
      if (shippedDisplay < totalShipped) {
        shippedDisplay += shippedStep;
        setTimeout(animateShipped, 100);
      }
    }
    animateShipped();
```

HTML:

```
<span id="shipped"></span>
```

What I want is for the element to automatically spin from 0 - 190 ONLY when the element is in the view of the browser and NOT actioned by scrolling....

As it is right now:
https://gyazo.com/6cd38177c44e97f0fa4f2b4d05ece5c3

Ideally I want all the number to be spinning, but let's focus on the "190" for now, when in view of the browser - any tips or suggestions would GREATLY be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

What I would suggest is set a timer on page load and use this [Jquery Visible](https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible) plugin to check if your element is in view before incrementing.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your isScrolledIntoView(elem) function is working you can do something like this:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  if(isScrolledIntoView($('#shipped'))){
    allInView();
  }
}, 100);
```

What it will do is checking every 100ms if your span is visible and then calling your allInView() function which then will animate the spinning.

If you do not want any overhead if the element is not visible you can deactivate the interval accordingly:

```
var interval = null;
function checkForAnimation(){
    if(isScrolledIntoView($('#shipped'))){
        interval = window.setInterval(function(){
                allInView();
            }, 100);
        }
    else{
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}
$(window).scroll(checkForAnimation);
```

Comment: Many thanks for this, although now the number loads as soon as the page is loaded, yet the element is near the bottom of the page: https://volocommerce.com :(

Comment: Actually I lie - it works when you start at the bottom and go up, but not starting at the bottom and going down

Comment: It seems to me that yout check for visibility is not working. Maybe you should try the plugin BG101 recommended in the post above.

Answer (score -1):

You can use setInterval(allInView(), 2);

Comment: How would calling the function once and passing the function's return variable to `setInterval` help?